# HTML save as dialog with file type selection

Tags: javascript, html

I am porting an application that runs in an applet into a javascript one. One feature in the old application is to let the user exporting generated data in different formats (PDF, csv, txt). The format of the generated file is chosen in the save as dialog, as you can see in the attached image, by selecting the file type. This, which is easy in Java using a JFileChooser, seems to be impossible in html. The ideal solution would be to display the save as dialog from the browser just to get the file name and type. Then, when the save button of the dialog is clicked and it is closed, the javascript application would call the server to download a file with the selected name and in the right format. The save as dialog would be displayed just to get the information, not to effectively saving anything. 
As this file filtering in the save dialog is a requirement in this migration project (everything must look the same as before), my question here is if it is possible to display a save as dialog with a file filter for some defined file types passed from javascript code. I cannot find the way to achive this.
[image]

Thanks.

Comment: show us what oyu have tried

Comment: Hi Philipp. At the moment, to make this all work I have three different buttons in my javascript application to download the data in the three different file types. Using FileSaver.js to get the name of the file before downloading doesn't help because I get again the save as file dialog after the is downloaded and I cannot display two times the save as dialog.